# Deciding when to implement OnClickListener in each view, or implementing activity to View.OnClickListener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In previous projects I have typically created an `OnClickListener` for any view which needed handle click interaction.

In more recent projects, I have implemented `View.OnClickListener`, and then overridden the `onClick` method of the activity to achieve the same result.

Is there an advantage in terms of performance of one implementation over the other, or is there a best practice for deciding which implementation is most appropriate for a particular situation?

Comment: Can you please share your xml layout?

Comment: update your android studio version and update sdk version also .refresh and load the project.

Comment: Share your app gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best practice defined by Android regarding registering click listeners. It totally depends on your use case.

Implementing the `View.OnClickListener` interface to Activity is the way to go. As Android strongly recommends interface implementation over and over again whether it is an Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Change version number from`26.1.0` to `26.4.0` in your dependencies

Comment: build -> clean project